Upwork All Jobs Listing Search through GrapghQl
I am using new upwork graphql api to fetch job search data, but it is only showing top 10 jobs of related search. I want all jobs with search filter. My current query looks like this with this api (https://api.upwork.com/graphql):
{
"query": "query marketplaceJobPostingsSearch($marketPlaceJobFilter: MarketplaceJobPostingsSearchFilter, $searchType: MarketplaceJobPostingSearchType, $sortAttributes: [MarketplaceJobPostingSearchSortAttribute]) { marketplaceJobPostingsSearch(marketPlaceJobFilter: $marketPlaceJobFilter, searchType: $searchType, sortAttributes: $sortAttributes) { totalCount edges { node { id title description category } } pageInfo { hasNextPage endCursor } } }",
"variables": {
"marketPlaceJobFilter": {
"titleExpression_eq": "JAVA"
},
"searchType": "USER_JOBS_SEARCH",
"sortAttributes": [
{ "field": "RECENCY" }
]
}
}
This returns recent 10 searches with JAVA keyword. How can I change for example I want all, or want top 100. This is the docs link **https://www.upwork.com/developer/documentation/graphql/api/docs/index.html#query-marketplaceJobPostingsSearch **
Is there a workaround, or did I just miss something?
I tried multiple ways as decrible in docs by using sinceId_eq variable and other implentation by follwing docs https://www.upwork.com/developer/documentation/graphql/api/docs/index.html#query-marketplaceJobPostingsSearch

Check marketPlaceJobFilter, it has pagination_eq, e.g.
{ "marketPlaceJobFilter":
  { "titleExpression_eq": "JAVA" },
  { "pagination_eq": { first: 100, after: "0" }}
}


And what about if I want to filter by category, and also display fields like no. Of connects, budget, no. Of bids etc

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
